# SurfaceView - Timestamp seems implausible relative to expectedPresent

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, surfaceview

For my barcode scanner app, I am leveraging parts of the [CameraSourcePreview class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/ui/camera/CameraSourcePreview.java) found in the Google Vision sample code.

I then leverage this class in my Fragment using this XML snippet:

```
<com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.barcode.CameraSourcePreview
    android:id="@+id/cameraSourcePreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
```

I have a function in my Fragment that launches an instance of this CameraSourcePreview when a button is pressed.

```
public void scanBarcode() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Barcode scanner called.");

    // Check for the camera permission before accessing the camera.  If the
    // permission is not granted yet, request permission.
    int rc = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    if (rc == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        createCameraSource();
    } else {
        requestCameraPermission();
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RC_HANDLE_CAMERA_PERM);
    }

    // Show & Hide CardViews for Barcode Scanner Function
    showField(cardViewBarcodeScanner);

    // Starting camera source
    startCameraSource();
}
```

When the view appears on screen and the camera starts, my Logcat starts getting spammed with these log items. They don't seem to affect performance, but I have no idea what it means and if it's something I should be worried about.

The only reference I can find to this error are from the AOSP framework code that exists on Github. Here is a [specific example](https://github.com/UnicornioSucio/android_frameworks_native/blob/56c2b8aa1d82f782ebe258259946e5ee0cd23bf2/services/surfaceflinger/BufferLayer.cpp) and here is a [broad search with all the results](https://github.com/search?q=seems%20implausible%20relative%20to%20expectedpresent&type=Code) I found, none of which seem to indicate exactly what causes the error when this SurfaceView appears.

The only thing I noticed is that I don't see these errors when I launch the Barcode Scanner / CameraSourcePreview in its own Activity (with just that and a LinearLayout element).

```
2018-08-26 22:10:24.608 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233137964798000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377402186342
2018-08-26 22:10:24.663 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233137996282000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377456284340
2018-08-26 22:10:24.687 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138032277000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377474317006
2018-08-26 22:10:24.752 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138117551000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377546447670
2018-08-26 22:10:24.846 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138173687000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377636611000
2018-08-26 22:10:24.862 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138205545000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377654643666
2018-08-26 22:10:24.898 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138244564000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377690708998
2018-08-26 22:10:24.951 1413-1413/? W/Layer: [SurfaceView - com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner/com.mattdonders.android.barcodescanner.MainActivity#0] Timestamp 233138311966000 seems implausible relative to expectedPresent 99377744806996
```

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and it is waaaay not expected behavior.  This is generating log files at the rate of about a dozen a second--overwhelming any useful logcat messages.  If this is expected behavior, something is really wrong in google's minds (even more than usual).

Comment: Do you have any updates or solutions on that problem?